# Unable to upgrade cdo to v1.9.7 on google cloud linux VM

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, cdo-climate

I am trying to install `CDO` v1.9.7 on my Linux VM on Google Cloud but it shows that the latest version available is 1.7. I am trying to regrid some netCDF files using `nctoolkit` but I can't do this with a `CDO` version >= 1.9.4

Please see the screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET8n3.png)

I have a personal linux machine which has v1.9.7 but I need the VM as its a GPU machine and I need to process massive datasets. Even though both are Linux I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: Please share your Linux distribution name and version, as you are using apt I suspect is a Debian or an Ubuntu VM instance. Also check if /etc/apt/sources.list have being modified.

Comment: You can potentially regrid using CDO version 1.7.0. nctoolkit can run with earlier versions of CDO, but I don't test it for compatibility. But if you can install conda/miniconda on google cloud, then I would go with a conda install

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the version from the Linux's OS is an stable version from Debian 10's repository is:

`Version: 1.9.6-1`

Please make a [backup](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) and  give a try to [clone the VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-similar-instance) and upgrade the OS's version:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Because it looks like from the picture you shared that there are a lot of upgrades available.

Please be aware that creating a snapshot as well as cloning the VM will produce an increased cost.